# I know it's been asked 1000x but nothing I try works. I can't delete a network file in windows. It's not in use. It's not a thumbnail issue

Tags: windows-7, permissions, pdf, network-shares, file-unlocking

I have a pdf, let's say \server\folder\file.pdf, that I cannot delete. I always get the standard windows error "the action cannot be completed because the file is  open in another program".

I don't run the server but I'm an administrator.

• The file is not in use locally. I have Unlocker, no locking handles found.
• I don't THINK another user is using it but can't confirm.
• "Net File" from command prompt doesn't show any locked files.

• I know that thumbnail caching can prevent me from deleting folders at times, but I already disabled it and can move/delete other files (including thumbs.db) without issue.

• Privileges are set to "full control" for every user... Everyone, USERS, Administrators, my username, system. File is not set to read-only.
• Googled and found other stuff involving cacls, computer management -> open files, resource monitor. Neither the file or its associated program (acrobat) are mentioned anywhere.

How is this still a thing that is apparently unknown and unsolvable after all these years?

Comment: "I don't THINK another user is using it but can't confirm." - Unless you are willing to risk data loss, without checking, rebooting the NAS should resolve this problem.  Unlocker will only indicate if the machine, its running on, is locking the file.  Unlocker is useless when checking the status of a file on a NAS.  "How is this still a thing that is apparently unknown and unsolvable after all these years?" - Because it's not actually an issue, it sounds like a configuration conflict, but without more information this specific part of the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply... I am willing to risk data loss, the file just needs to be deleted. But I cannot reboot the NAS. I'm frustrated because even if the file really is being used by some other user, why can I not see that via "net file" which in turn would let me kill it with Net File [whatever] /close ? And if nobody is using it, then what IS the issue? That's the part that feels like it's been a windows problem forever... files randomly getting locked for no reason.

Comment: Why can't you reboot the NAS?

Comment: I'm not the administrator of this network. I have an account with some admin privileges but I can't physically access or reboot other machines.